# spring boot 2. @Bean method invoked before injecting @Autowired dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, configuration, autowired

This is just curiosity. 
In example below @Autowired EntityManagerFactory and @Autowired ApplicationContext are injected before @Bean entityManager() method.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;


    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

But when i change EntityManager bean type to SessionFactory then sessionFactory() method is invoked before autowiring EntityManagerFactory and ApplicationContext beans causing NullPointerException when unwrapping SessionFactory. Code snippet below

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

And my question is: Why is this happening?

Comment: I believe you are doing this wrong..
Can you unwrap session like this Session session = unwrap(Session.class); then get session.getSessionFactory(); do reply

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am not asking about the way how to do this properly. I am just curious why `@Bean` definition is once invoked after autowiring other fields (i.e. `@Bean` type is EntityManagerFactory) and once it is invoked  before autowiring other fields (i.e. Bean type is SessionFactory). I just would like to know the reason behind this because i couldn't find answer for my own

Comment: I don't think it (@bean) is invoked before the autowiring other fields because that will be the violation of java JVM. As, JVM doesn't let any method call to happen till all the data member fields are initialized.

Comment: Depending on your version of Hibernate the `EntityManagerFactory` is the `SessionFactory`.

Comment: @M.Deinum YES that's it. My second code snippet was throwing NPE at `entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);` because i was defining SessionFactory bean and SessionFactory extends EntityManagerFactory nowadays. That's why Bean definition was invoked before Autowiring. Convert your comment to answer and i will mark it as a accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Hibernate 5.2 the [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) is also an `EntityManagerFactory` as it now extends said interface. Prior to this the [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) was wrapping an `EntityManagerFactory`.

Due to this the `EntityManagerFactory` cannot be injected because the `SessionFactory` is the actual bean implementing that interface.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember there are two ways to obtain the `SessionFactory`:
**From EntityManagerFactory**

```
return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)
//or -> if you have entitymanager
return em.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

**From Session**

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
return session.getSessionFactory();
```

And the reasons you are curious like as you said

> sessionFactory() method is invoked before autowiring EntityManagerFactory and   ApplicationContext beans causing NullPointerException

**This is not the case**